# How to implement design in OOP

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml

I have following structure

[image]

- One organization can have many environments.
- One environment can have many Applications.
- One application can have many Policis.

---

I created class of each entities i.e.

- class Organization,
- class Environment,
- class Application,
- class Policy

Now I want to apply policies to Application.
One policy should have one `Policy` class object. All instances of Policy are different. Every policy have unique name and ID.

Inheritance will not work, Consider following hierarchy -

- Organization
- Environment(Organization)
- API(Environment)
- Policy(API)

because every policy, required to procide all details of API, Environment, Organization.

Can we do aggregation here? Need help on this

Comment: `Now I want to apply policies to Application. One policy should have one Policy class object` do you mean all instances of Policy are 'different' ? be more clear please. `Inheritance will not work` inheritance between which classes ?

Comment: @bruno  all instances of Policy are 'different >> yes, also Updated question

Comment: Is every policy only about Application? In other words, if I would take an application and move it to another environment or organization, could the policy stay unchanged ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All instances of Policy are different.
> Every policy have unique name and ID

You can indicate that with the constraint :

```
Policy.allInstances() -> forAll(p1, p2 |
  p1 <> p2 implies (p1.name <> p2.name and p1.ID <> p2.ID))
```

A class diagram from the information you give can be :

[image]

I do not use bidirectional relations supposing *Policy* does not know the associated *Application*(s) whose does not know associated *Environment*(s) whose does not know associated *Organization*(s).

I use multiplicities `*` equivalent to `0..*` because nothing in your question says the minimum multiplicity is 1 each time. I do not indicate the multiplicity in the opposite direction of the relations because your question does not indicate something about them.

> Inheritance will not work

`A inherits B` implies `A is a B`, among the classes your give none of them satisfy that, so there is no possible inheritance between them.

> Can we do aggregation here

may be between *Environment* and *Application* because we can say an environment is composed by applications, but else where no.